# how to add image as logo using balsamiq wire frame maker?

Tags: wireframe, balsamiq

I am designing a wireframe in [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/). I want to add an image as logo can any one help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you are using, here is the way to import an image to your Balsamiq project:

- Mockups 3 for Desktop: https://docs.balsamiq.com/desktop/images/#adding-images-in-mockups-view
- myBalsamiq (our web version): https://docs.balsamiq.com/mybalsamiq/images/#adding-images

Please let us know if you need anything else, we're here to help! (support@balsamiq.com)

-Virgin from Balsamiq